# How to temporarily stop time syncing with domain controller?

Tags: sql-server, domain-controller, local-system, time

I wish to do some testing on my local machine which requires me to put the date forward a year. So I can test some stuff in SQL Server (i've found it not possible to override the sql server time).

However because I'm connected to a domain, I believe this is causing the time to be reset to normal a few moments after I try to override it.

I understand that it's probably important for the local and domain time to be insync, but is it possible to temporarily block the clock from being reset?

Disconnecting from the network isn't an option, as I require an internet connection.

If there is a manual way to block the time reset what are the likely reprocutions? I don't want to screw anything up on the network :-)

Comment: Would disabling the Windows Time service be acceptable?

Comment: yep disabling time service would do the trick..

Comment: Just be aware that if the SQL machine's time gets too far out of sync with the DCs, authentication will fail.

Comment: If you're doing this on virtual machine, make sure to **disable Time synchronization** on your host VM manager because none of the above suggestions will otherwise work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open the registry editor (`regedit`), navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters
```

Find the `REG_SZ` value named `Type`. Edit the value to `NoSync`. Set it back to `Nt5DS` when you need to sync with the domain hierarchy again.

You can do this from the command line by calling

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters /v Type /d NoSync /f
```

or in PowerShell, with:

```
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters -Name "Type" -Value "NoSync"
```

Comment: Interestingly my type value Type was set to NTP. So perhaps it was actually a NTP server setting which I couldn't see due to a domain policy or something.

Comment: In some domain configurations, you might want to set the `Type` to `NTP` and add a specific DC to your list of NTP Sources, eg. if you have no DC's in your Site, and want to specify a remote DC with better connectivity than you have with the PDC Emulator.

Answer (score 10):

Disable the Windows Time service or block the outbound port 123 on your local firewall.

Answer (score -1):

You can type this in the cmd terminal to stop the Windows Time Sync. It does  what you needed in Window OS.

```
net stop w32time
```

[windows](/questions/tagged/windows)